# Beta-function non-zero at classical level?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization

In Jaume Gomis's [lecture 5](http://www.perimeterscholars.org/327.html#top) on CFT at Perimeter Institute, he says (at 27:40 minute mark) that the beta function, *classically*, of the $m^2$ parameter in massive $\lambda \phi^4$ theory is

$$\beta(m^2) = -2m^2\,.$$

The intuitive reasoning he gives is that since the dimension of $m^2$ is 2, then the beta function should be -2 times m-squared.

I always thought that the beta functions for parameters of the Lagrangian only start at one-loop and are classically zero.  What is the rigorous definition of a beta function (including the classical part)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The theory is (even classically) not scale invariant. Just by dimensional analysis, you can note that the scalar field has *scaling dimension* 1, and the mass (as the name suggests) must also have a scaling dimension of 1. So $m^2$ has a ascaling dimension of 2, which suggests the RG equation which you've written in the question. That essentially says that the $m^2$ parameter decreases exponentially, but with scaling dimension 2 as you go to the UV.

Only when you have couplings which are classically dimensionless, do the RG equations have no tree level contributions.  eg: coefficients of dimension 4 operators: like $\lambda$ in $\lambda \phi^4$ or $g$ in $g \phi \bar{\psi} \psi $

FYI: Tree level is equivalent to *classical* field theory and loop contributions are like quantum corrections. You can see that by restoring powers of $\hbar$ in the path integral.

Comment: Thanks!  but I already understand it qualitatively.  I want to know the formal definition:  why the minus sign? how to connect it to the 't Hooft parameter $\mu$.  And it's relation to the 'anomalous dimension' $\gamma(m^2)$...  Thanks!

Comment: By the `t Hooft parameter $\mu$, do you mean the anomalous scale you get while doing dim reg? That is a quantum phenomenon (since you get it from dim reg on _loop_ integrals). In the classical theory, $m^2$ does not have anomalous scaling. Quantum (loop) corrections to the scaling dimension are what we call _anomalous_. The minus sign is kinda by definition, because something with a positive mass dimension increases as you flow to the IR and decreases as you flow to the UV. Since increasing $\Lambda$ corresponds to going towards the UV, we need a negative sign.

Comment: Yes $\mu$ is dim-reg parameter.  So, if I understand you correctly?  Is it true, *in all cases* the *classical* beta function for a parameter, $x$, of mass-dimension $[x]$ is ALWAYS $\beta(x) = -[x]\times x$?  Thank you again!  So how do I write out the full thing with quantum corrections (involving the anomalous part $\gamma$)?  Is it $\beta(x) = -[x]\times x + \gamma(x)$?  Is that the *exact* correct formula?

Comment: Yes, the loop-corrected RGE will become (small correction to what you wrote) $\beta(x) = - ([x]+\gamma(x)) x$.  $\gamma(x)$ is called the _anomalous_ scaling dimension, since it's a correction to $[x]$. Here, the RHS shows only the leading order in $x$; in general there could also be higher order terms.