# $\beta$-function in free massive scalar field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, renormalization, conformal-field-theory

It is well-known that *interacting* QFTs with conformal symmetry preserved at the quantum level have a vanishing $\beta$-function. Another common statement is that mass terms break conformal invariance.

The free massless scalar field is conformal, and adding a mass term breaks the conformal invariance. Although it is still commonly called "free", I think you could view the mass term $m^2 \phi \phi$ as an interaction term between two scalar fields. After all, what is the difference between $m^2 \phi^2$ and $\lambda \phi^4$, apart from the number of fields being coupled in the vertex?

So is there some sort of a $\beta$-function related to the mass? If yes, how would it look like? Or does the statement above only make sense when there is a coupling constant for $n \geq 3$ fields for some reason?

Comment: Yes you can treat the mass term as an interaction. I haven't done the calculation, but I am pretty sure that the $\beta$ function would be proportional to the mass (squared).

Comment: @Oбжорoв Thanks! I would do the computation, but I am not sure where to start. The free massive two-point function is known exactly and is a Bessel function in position space. Can I read the exact $\beta$-function off that expression somehow?

Comment: I mean, it is clear that the 1st order correction to a free massless scalar field is $-m^2/p^4$, which can easily be obtained either by expanding the exact propagator $1/(p^2+m^2)$ (I'm in Euclidean space) or by writing down the (rather trivial) diagram. But how is there a dependence on the scale?

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly Which part exactly? (the link brings me to the actual question by the way, but I found the post you meant)

Comment: @Jxx Wow, sorry about the incorrect link in my first comment. I guess you figured it out, but here's the correct link for convenience: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/303611. I was referring to this sentence in AccidentalFourierTransform's answer: "we are not considering on-shell parameters (e.g., pole masses), as *these are defined at a particular (fixed) energy scale*." It may not completely answer what you're asking, but I thought it might be a helpful perspective.

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly I see. Yeah $m^2$ is here a pole mass, so it doesn’t run I guess? But then, is there anything that runs in this theory? And if not, why is it not conformal? (I know it’s not conformal, the question is meant from the point of view of the $\beta$-function)

Comment: @Jxx There are at least two different (closely related) versions of the renormalization group. One is tailored for experimental particle physics: the model is fixed, but we choose to parameterize it in terms of quantities that are defined at whatever energy scale we care about. That's where AFT's answer was coming from.

Comment: @Jxx Another version is tailored for theoretical physics: the model is *not* fixed, but rather we ask what change in its parameters gives the same effect as an overall spatial dilation (of the whole quantum theory, not just of the lagrangian). In this version, the mass *does* run. The mass is inversely related to the correlation length, and an overall spatial dilation changes the correlation length. In the limit of extreme dilation, we stretch the correlation length to infinity -- the mass goes to zero, and we arrive at a scale-invariant fixed point.

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly Many thanks for your comment, I feel like I only have a vague understanding of what you are saying. I tried to reproduce the textbook analysis of the $\beta$-function when considering $m^2$ as some coupling constant, but I failed since without infinities and counterterms it looks quite different. It should be easy to get a concrete expression though..

Answer (score 1):

The concrete answer is actually in this post: [Beta-function non-zero at classical level?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/64905/beta-function-non-zero-at-classical-level)

In short, the $\beta$-function for the mass is just:

$$\beta(m^2) = -2 m^2. \tag{1}$$

I am sure there are many ways to see that, e.g. the one described in the post. Here is another (trivial) way to check it. The renormalization group equation reads:

$$\left\lbrace p \frac{\partial}{\partial p} - \beta(m^2) \frac{\partial}{\partial m^2} + 2 - 2 \gamma_m \right\rbrace G^{(2)} (p;m^2) = 0\,, \tag{2}$$

where $g^{(2)} (p;m^2)$ is the exact propagator, i.e. (in Euclidean space):

$$G^{(2)}(p;m^2) = \frac{1}{p^2 + m^2}\,. \tag{3}$$

In a free theory the mass does not have an anomalous dimension, so $\gamma_m = 0$. The RGE can now be solved for $\beta(m^2)$, and we obtain the result mentioned above.

Comment: Usually in the Callan-Symanzik equation we have a term $\mu\frac{\partial}{\partial\mu}$. Why is this term replaced with $p\frac{\partial}{\partial p}$? Also, where does the $2$ comes from?